# Cambiar miniperfil SO en español

Tags: bug, estado-no-reproducido

Recientemente cambie mi **nombre visible de usuario** de juan1992 a Juan Pinzón, quiero insertar el miniperfil en un sitio web que administro, pero el miniperfil de SO en español sigue apareciendo como juan1992, revise en SO en ingles y ahí ya cambio a Juan Pinzón, incluso aquí en meta ya se realizo el cambio. **¿Que podría hacer para solucionarlo?**

[image: Cambios no aparecen]

Comment: Hola @Juan. ¿Has intentado realizar esto nuevamente? Veo que demoró un tiempo en actualizarse.

Comment: Cambiar nuevamente el **Nombre de usuario**?

Comment: Perdón, me refería a revisar el mini perfil. Acabo de revisar ahora tu mini perfil y ya luce actualizado con tu nombre.

Comment: Si ahora mismo lo hice y sigue apareciendo como lo muestro en la imagen

Comment: Qué extraño. Quizás intenta refrescando la página o accediendo desde otro navegador o desde la navegación privada. Yo veo que el enlace y la imagen muestran tu nuevo nombre de usuario.

Comment: Si, eso mismo estaba viendo, voy a probar eliminando la cache del navegador para ver si funciona

Comment: ¿¿¿Funcionó????

Comment: Sí, con eso ya se arreglo el problema

Comment: Jaja, era el cache.